# Connection between machines via GRE tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, tunnel

I have two machines: `machineA`: `192.168.0.1` and `machineB`: `192.168.0.2`. Both machines run on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. The machines see each other, it is possible to run from `machineB`:

```
sudo tcpdump -i devB # the name of "standard" interface
```

and run from `machineA`:

```
ping 192.168.0.2
```

and receive informations about packets' exchange on `machineB`.

I would like to establish communication between mentioned machines via GRE tunnel. I perform following steps:

**`machineA`:**

```
sudo ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 192.168.0.2 local 192.168.0.1 ttl 255
sudo ip link set up dev gre1
sudo ip address add 192.168.0.10/24 dev gre1 # I have taken this address from nowhere, it's imaginary
```

**`machineB`:**

```
sudo ip tunnel add gre2 mode gre remote 192.168.0.1 local 192.168.0.2 ttl 255
sudo ip link set up dev gre2
sudo ip address add 192.168.0.20/24 dev gre2 # I have taken this address from nowhere, it's imaginary
```

Then, I would expect the machines to be able to communicate via GRE tunnel. But when I run on `machineB`:

```
sudo tcpdump -i gre2
```

and run on `machineA`:

```
ping 192.168.0.2 # or
ping 192.168.0.10 # or
ping 192.168.0.20
```

all packets are transmitted and received, but I don't see any output on `machineB`.

Maybe the problem lie in my lack of understanding of how GRE tunnels work. In most tutorials there is written about routers, but I am not touching any router, just configure everything using terminals in machines. Could you tell me where I am making a mistake, how to solve the problem (be able to see that communication is made via GRE tunnel)?

Comment: You might be missing ip forwarding on machineA. Try `sudo echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf` and `sudo sysctl -p`. See [link](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/linux-setup-gre-tunnel/?PageSpeed=noscript).

Comment: The change you have mentioned didn't help, but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use inside the tunnel the same IP LAN network (192.168.0.0/24) as the IP addresses in use by the network of the endpoints, then the routes automatically added will share the previous network, and usually they won't be used, since there's already a previous route *outside* the tunnel. That's also related to the fact that Linux uses the [weak host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model), thus sharing its IP addresses on all its interfaces.

This can be simply verified by asking the kernel (here on machineA) what route will be chosen:

```
# ip route get 192.168.0.2
192.168.0.2 dev devA src 192.168.0.1 uid 0 
    cache 
# ip route get 192.168.0.20
192.168.0.20 dev devA src 192.168.0.1 uid 0 
    cache
```

Despite:

```
# ip route
192.168.0.0/24 dev devA proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev gre1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.10
```

Just assign IP addresses from an other IP network to remove the route ambiguity. For example 192.168.10.0/24:

machineA:

```
# ip address flush dev gre1
# ip address add 192.168.10.10/24 dev gre1
```

machineB:

```
# ip address flush dev gre2
# ip address add 192.168.10.20/24 dev gre2
```

machineA:

```
# ip route get 192.168.10.20
192.168.10.20 dev gre1 src 192.168.10.10 uid 0 
    cache
```

Now traffic will use the tunnel.